# hola me colaboran porfa?

Tags: html, css, mediaqueries

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hola soy principiante en programación y no se cual es mi error estoy trabajando con @media al momento de entrar desde un celular las medidas no se aplica [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por lo visto, está mal estructurado tu código, la clase está saliéndose de las llaves del @media

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple vista, la clase `.navegacion-principal` está afuera de las llaves del `@media`. Para que funcione los media Queries, las clases deben estar dentro de ellos, de esta forma las propiedades de dichas clases ocurrirán cuando se cumplan los `@medias` (el alto o ancho de la pantalla).

Tu código sería así:

```
@media (min-width: 480px){
   .navegacion-principal{
      flex-direction: row;
   }
}
```

Comment: gracias cris223511.dev